# How to log into other Desktop Environment (Deepin)?

Tags: desktop-environments, gdm

Since the Deeping Desktop Environment looks extremely sexy I wanted to try it out on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation (must not distrohop, but whatever.. :-)  ). So following [the instructions on this page](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/how-to-install-deepin-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-18-04) I installed it succesfully and (as instructed) I chose GDM3 as my display manager.

I then logged out to try to log back in with Deeping. The instructions say I need to select Deepin under the "Cog icon", but in my screen (see below) I don't see any cog icon.

Does anybody know what's wrong here? How can I login to Deeping? All tips are welcome!

[image]

Comment: have you not restarted and see if the cog wheel is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer turns out the be simple: I first had to click my name so that I can fill in my password. Next to the "Log in" button the cog item is show which makes it possible to log into Deepin.

Hopefully this helps someone else looking for the same thing.

Comment: accept your own answer, so the green tick mark comes.

Comment: @PRATAP - I wanted to do that, but I can only do that 2 days after I gave the answer. So I just need to wait.